# How can I immutable update an array and store it in local storage in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, jsx, immutability

I'm making a recipe app. I want useres to be able to add recipes to a list of favorites. There are 3 React components involved. Recipe, AddToFavorites, and Favorites.

The Recipe component shows various details about the selected recipe.

The AddToFavorites component is a button that is rendered in the Recipe component.

The Favorites component is a list that displays all items added to favorites with the add to favorites button.

```
function Favorites() {
  const [favList, setFavList] = useState(localStorage.getItem('favorites'));
  return (
    <FavPageContainer>
      {favList}
      {favList.map(listItem => {
        <li>{listItem}</li>
      })}
    </FavPageContainer>
  )
}
```

```
function Recipe() {
  let params = useParams();
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('summary');
  const fetchDetails = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${params.name}/information?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`);
    const detailData = await data.json();
    setDetails(detailData);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDetails();
  }, [params.name]);

  return (
    <DetailWrapper>
        <h2>{details.title}</h2>
        <img src={details.image} alt="" />

      <Info>
        <ButtonContainer>
          <AddToFavorites details={details}/>
          <Button 
            className={activeTab === 'summary' ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => setActiveTab('summary')}>Nutrition Info
          </Button>
          <Button 
            className={activeTab === 'ingredients' ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => setActiveTab('ingredients')}>Ingredients
          </Button>
          <Button
            className={activeTab === 'instructions' ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => setActiveTab('instructions')}>Instructions
          </Button>
        </ButtonContainer>
        {activeTab === 'instructions' && (
          <div>
            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: details.instructions}}></p>
          </div>
        )}
        {activeTab === 'ingredients' && (
          <ul>
          {details.extendedIngredients &&
            details.extendedIngredients.map((ingredient) => (
              <li key={ingredient.id}> {ingredient.original}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
         {activeTab === 'summary' && (
          <div>
            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: details.summary}}></p>
          </div>
        )}
      </Info>
    </DetailWrapper>
  )
}
```

```
function AddToFavorites(details) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState([]);
  const handleActive = () => {
      setActive(!active);
  };

  const handleFavorites = () => {
    handleActive();
    if(active){
      removeFromFavorites();
    } else if(!active) {
      addToFavorites();
  }
};

  const addToFavorites = () => {
    handleActive();
      setFavorites([...favorites, details]);
      console.log(favorites)
      localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
  };
 
return (
  <AddToFavBtn className={active ? 'active' : null} onClick={handleFavorites}>
      {!active ? 'Add to favorites' : 'Remove from favorites'}
      <div>
      <BsFillSuitHeartFill/>
      </div>
  </AddToFavBtn>
)
}
```

What I've tried to do so far:

- Pass API data to AddToFavorites as 'details' props in Recipe.
- Set favorites as a state defaulting to an empty array in AddToFavorites.
- Add onClick event to add to favorites btn in AddToFavorites, which calls AddToFavorites() function.
- In the AddToFavorites() function I've tried to immutably update the favorites state by using the spread operator and adding the received details props (which has the API data) as a new item in the new copy of the state array, then store it in local storage.

What happens when I add an item to favorites is that I can add one item, and I can add it multiple times. But when I go to a new recipe to add another item, it deletes the old items and restarts.

I've been going over it and trying different things for a few days, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think you want `function AddToFavorites({ details }) {`. The first parameter passed to function components is a _props_ **object**

Comment: What data are you trying to store in `localStorage`? Is it just identifiers or complete data objects? Be mindful that there are storage size limits (typically 5MB)

Comment: I'm just going to render the recipe image and title which will be a link which will take the user to the recipe page. So I only need the image, title, and route.

Comment: Do the recipes have an `id` property or similar?

Comment: Yes, each recipe has an id property.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good case for shared state. If your *favourites* data is managed in a single place, you won't run into synchronising issues when adding, removing or displaying.

I would recommend creating a context

```jsx
import {
  createContext,
  useCallback,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";

const FavoritesContext = createContext({
  favorites: [],
  toggleFavorite: () => {},
  isFavorite: () => false,
}); // default context value

export const FavoritesContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const preloadRef = useRef(false);

  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites")) ?? []
  );

  // assuming favourites have IDs
  const ids = useMemo(
    () => new Set(favorites.map(({ id }) => id)),
    [favorites]
  );
  const isFavorite = useCallback((id) => ids.has(id), [ids]);

  // sync data on change
  useEffect(() => {
    // skip initial preload
    if (preloadRef.current) {
      localStorage.setItem("favorites", JSON.stringify(favorites));
    }
    preloadRef.current = true;
  }, [favorites]);

  const toggleFavorite = ({ id, image, title, route }) => {
    if (isFavorite(id)) {
      setFavorites((prev) => prev.filter((fav) => fav.id !== id));
    } else {
      setFavorites((prev) => [...prev, { id, image, title, route }]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <FavoritesContext.Provider
      value={{ favorites, toggleFavorite, isFavorite }}
    >
      {children}
    </FavoritesContext.Provider>
  );
};

// hook helper
export const useFavorites = () => useContext(FavoritesContext);
```

Then wrap the relevant part of your application with the context provider, eg

```jsx
<FavoritesContextProvider>
  <App />
</FavoritesContextProvider>
```

and wherever you need to read or modify *favourites*, use the context hook

```js
// read
const { favorites } = useFavorites();

// modify
const { isFavorite, toggleFavorite } = useFavorites();
```

---

You could also use any other form of state management like Redux.